# express builder

Tags: ms-access

I have a question about Access database. I'm creating a form. I have a retail price that I want to get a 5% discount from to make a sale price. The sale price is the retail price - the discount but I cannot figure it out. I have been trying this but it does not give me what I want in express builder.

```
=IIf([Retail Price]>20,0.05*[retail price],0.02*[sale price])
```

I've tried many different combinations but can't get it.

Comment: So you only want to have a five percent discount if the price is greater than $20 otherwise two percent of sale price? Then you want to subtract this value from the retail price?

Comment: Note that `retail price - 5% of retail price` is the same as `95% of retail price`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
=IIf([Retail Price]>20,[Retail Price]-(0.05*[retail price]),[Retail Price]-(0.02*[retail price]))
```